# requests from Aminer API

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to python and web-scraping. I need to find all the publications for a specific topic such as "healthcare" with the corresponding authors from Aminer API. Here is the documentation http://doc.aminer.org/en/latest/s/pub/basic.html
and my attempt:

```
import requests
par = {'query': 'healthcare'}
re = requests.get('https://api.aminer.org/api/search/person', params=par)
print(re.text)
```

which gives me empty result. However, it works when I enter it in "https://www.hurl.it". Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the API has a restriction on `User-Agent`, so I passed the user agent from my browser (Chrome):

```
import requests
par = {'query': 'healthcare'}
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}
re = requests.get('https://api.aminer.org/api/search/person', params=par, headers=headers)
print(re.text)
```

And it now returns the content. May not be the proper way to call an API but that's a bit out of the API user's hands

Comment: Thanks. It seems that there is a size parameter that only allows less than 100 outputs. I'm trying to make a txt file like one of these scraped from Aminer:  aminer.org/lab-datasets/crossdomain for another topic like healthcare. Is there anyway to generate more than 100 outputs like they did in those files?

Comment: You can use the `offset` parameter get the next 100 and so on